# How to loop through rows in table using a function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a test plan template for work which contains a table with various fields with each row being identified by the "Test No" column. When adding a test case, i want it to check to see if the test case that has been entered is already in the table.

Im attempting to do this using a function which passes in a parameter which is the test case number being entered. I want this to loop through my rows and if a matching case is found, i want an error message to be displayed and it to exit the sub. This is what i have so far but it doesnt seem to work.

Function:

```
Function ExistingTest(x As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim intStartRow     As Integer
    Dim intStartCol     As Integer
    Dim intRowCount     As Integer
    Dim intColCount     As Integer
    Dim TestTable       As String

    TestTable = "Tests"

    intRowCount = Range(TestTable).Rows.Count
    intColCount = Range(TestTable).Columns.Count
    intStartRow = Range(TestTable).Rows(0).Row
    intStartCol = Range(TestTable).Columns(1).Column

    ExistingTest = False

    For i = 1 To intRowCount
    If Range(TestTable).Rows(i).Columns(1).value = x Then
        ExistingTest = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
  End Function
```

Code in main block:

```
    If ExistingTest(TNName) Then
    response = MsgBox("ERROR: Test Evidence for Test Number " + TNName + " Already exists")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working? Throwing an error? Wrong results --- if so, wrong in what way?

Comment: Are you using an actual Excel Table or just a named range?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a loop for this you can use the function "CountIf" to count the amount of recurrences of the ID.

Also you do not need a special function for this, just use data validation. 
Data > Data Validation > Custom 
Add the following formula, assuming your data starts in A2 and the IDs are in column A, Adjust this is ifneeded

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1
```

That's it the person will be able to enter only unique IDs now.

If you still want to use the user defined function look at this example that also uses CountIf

```
Function ExistingTest(ByVal r As Range, ByVal strNamedRange As String) As Boolean
    ExistingTest = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(strNamedRange).Columns(1), r.Value)

End Function


Sub MainBlock()

    If ExistingTest(TNName, "Test") Then
        response = MsgBox("ERROR: Test Evidence for Test Number " + TNName + " Already exists")
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks